# How to make x-ticks more visible?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a `matplotlib` plot which I'm creating with the following code:

```
# Plot times for completion
print "Plotting Completion Times"    
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.title("Completion Times")
plt.xlabel("Times (In Seconds)")
plt.xticks(x, x)
plt.ylabel("Percentage of completion")

plt.show()
```

The plot comes out correctly, but the `xticks` which I have set on the x-axis end up overlapping and now I can't read them properly. The resultant x-axis ticks look like this:

[image]

You can see that there are five marked points, but I don't know what any of their full values are.

Is there a way I can make the values display at an angle so that they are all fully visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can basically set explicitly the steps between xticks distance by `plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))` they will be evenly spaced with 1.0 distance between each tick from min(x) to max(x)+1, you can increase 1.0 to any value that is confortable with you